# JavaFx bind entity model to TableView

Tags: java, mysql, entity, javafx-2, fxml

I have JavaFx application with TableView and MySQL database.

I have create entity model(Products) from database.

Have `ObservableList<Products> proList;`

How i can fill this `proList` from database and then bind my `@FXML private TableView<Products> tableView;`?

Im very very new in JavaFx.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your start/initialize method,
First load your entity list (assuming JPA):

```
List<Products> productEntityList = 
    entityManager.createQuery("select p from Products p").getResultList(); // or better use your service classes to fetch data
```

Second init the ObservableList with fetched data:

```
proList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(productEntityList);
```

Third set the items of the table view:

```
tableView.setItems(proList);
```

Note that any changes (add/remove) made to proList will be reflected to tableView.getItems() too.

Comment: please tell me how to initilize EntityManager

Comment: There are sufficient resources about the JPA and entitymanager on the net. Still if you are having difficulties ask here in new question.